# Dialogflow fulfillment doesn't work after intent is already mapped

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I just started learning dialogflow, and I am following the instruction [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/fulfillment) to make fulfillment on intent.  However I can't make it work even though it seem to be correct, what am I doing wrong?

I create the buy-car intent with webhook enabled:

[image]

Fulfillment is enabled and the intent is already mapped:

[image]

```
  function BuyCar(agent) {
    agent.add(`Sure I can help you with that`);
    agent.add(`Web hook response`);
    agent.end("");
  }
  
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('Buy-Car', BuyCar);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

No response thought:

[image]

In diagnostics, it gave this error for fulfillment:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The following error also appear in log, what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: I tried your code with a test intent that is trained with "buy a car" statement at it works fine for me. Can you show your package.json as well? Also did you use [this git example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) as your base code?

Comment: Hi Ricco, I was able to fix it by removing multiple response, does dialogflow not support multiple responses?     
    agent.add(`Sure I can help you with that`);
    agent.add(`Web hook response`);

Comment: I see that is weird. I did not yet encounter any errors related to multiple responses. You can create a new question related to your problem on multiple responses.

Comment: Ah I think it's because the Web Demo I am using to test it does not support rich text or multiple response, which is pretty dumb because that's the most simple built in testing platform by Google.

Comment: I see, yes the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/web-demo#limits) indicated that. You can try testing on other integrations like Dialogflow messenger or the test console located on the right side of dialogflow console just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by testing multi line responses in the Web Demo provided by Dialogflow console. The Web Demo is limited to "single text responses" only. See [Web Demo limitations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/web-demo#limits) for reference.

If the responses are multi line or have rich messages, a possible  workaround is to execute testing in the "test console" located at the right side of the Dialogflow console or try using a different integration like the Dialogflow Messenger.